# Accessing content scaleFactor / multiplier?

Tags: ios, view, swift

I am working on an iPhone 6 Plus, and getting the bounds of my UIView using:

```
let viewBounds = view.bounds // GIVES 736 x 414 (Points), WHICH IS RIGHT
```

Is there any way that I can get the multiplier (i.e. the @3x) that is used to convert the points into pixels. I was hoping that I could use:

```
let scaleFactor = view.contentScaleFactor // GIVES 1
```

But as you can see it always seems to return 1. I know that I can grab the screen size directly using `preferredMode.size` or `nativeBounds` but I am sure there was a way before to access the multiplier too?

```
// WHERE SCALE FACTOR WOULD BE 3
let yRes = viewBounds.height * scaleFactor // 736 x 3 = 2208
let xRes = viewBounds.width * scaleFactor //  414 x 3 = 1242
```

Comment: what does the `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` say? that should give you the correct scale factor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the [*`UIView` Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentScaleFactor) documentation says about `contentScaleFactor` property:

> (...) For system views, the value of this property may be `1.0` even on high resolution screens.

therefore that is not what you look for.

---

the actual scale factor can be read from the main screen, that will give you either `1.0`, `2.0` or even `3.0`:

```
let scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale // Swift3, Swift4.x
let scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale // Swift 2.x
```

or

```
CGFloat _scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; // Obj-C
```

you can read more about the `scale` property in the [*`UIScreen` Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale).

Comment: Perfect thank you, I could have sworn that was on UIView, no wonder I could not find it. Much appreciated Sir.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3.0

```
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
```